# Google Closure Compiler not recognizing type annotation

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-closure-compiler

I'm attempting to compile ExtJS 6.2.0 with Google's Closure Compiler. There's annotations like the following in the extjs source code:

`* @param {Ext.data.TreeModel[]} records An array of records.`

Closure errors out as it doesn't recognize this type of annotation. The error looks like the following:

```
extjs-6.2.0/build/ext-all-debug.js:248792: ERROR - Bad type annotation. expecting a variable name in a @param tag. See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Bad-Type-Annotation for more information.
     * @param {Ext.data.TreeModel[]} data.records An Array of Models representing the
```

I don't necessarily see a solution in the URL provided. There's also an abundance of types in ExtJS like this that I'm guessing the compiler is going to have issues with.

Is there a trivial workaround here? I could remove `--jscomp_error checkTypes` from compilation, but I'd rather do this the proper way.

Answer (score 3):

The annotation you show is not compatible with google closure compiler. Instead it would be written

```
* @param {Array<Ext.data.TreeModel>} records An array of records.
```

I suspect they are using JSDoc because the annotation `Ext.data.TreeModel[]` is compatible with JSDoc, see http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html.

Closure Compiler started off with the JSDoc syntax, but the two have diverged a bit over the last 5 years or so. The closure compiler annotations are described here: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler (scroll to Type Expressions at the bottom).

It might be possible to change a few annotations to make it compatible with closure compiler.  But there are some assumptions about how the code works that are used with ADVANCED mode of the compiler, which this code might not follow.  See [a recent thread about a similar question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/closure-compiler-discuss/bwiEhiVbBnM/2Mba6SxbDgAJ).